ASP .NET Blazor pages route transitions
I am somewhat new to Blazor pages and come from a background with Angular and am aware for long loading async pages I can use route animates or skeleton loaders. I have skeleton loaders on a Razor page but my issue more comes from when that page is loaded it is making an expensive API call so I would like to show a progress bar because right now from say the home page you hit the route in the nav bar and then nothing happens for a solid 5 seconds until the page loads and the skeleton loader is shown ever so briefly. I am using memoryCache so next time it's not as bad but regardless been trying to google how to handle this better. Can someone point me in the right direct?

so, you can see here the yellow click is when I hit it and then finally at the end the content loads but during that whole time the home screen is still shown and that's the main issue I would like to solve
I have even tried this but it still results in a very long pause before the page loads with the progress bar
    @if (loading == true)
{
    <div class="progress mt-3">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"></div>
    </div>
} else{
...content here...
}

@code {
    public Boolean loading = true;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
....
loading = false;
}




Is this WASM? Mixed? What is going on before loading = false;?

Have you considered using a different lifecycle event? Show your progress bar in OnInitializedAsync, but do your expensive process in OnAfterRenderAsync only when firstRender is true.

OnAfterRenderAsync is not a  lifecycle event, it's a UI event.

LOL! OK, you should tell Microsoft they're wrong. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0. It's part of the Render lifecycle.

so using the OnAfterRenderAsync worked better in terms of page load - the calls finish but the template is not marked to be checked or updates so the skelton loaders never go away

The following page illustrates how to show a loading message with no delays.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@if (!_isInteractive)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning m-5">Pre-Rendering</div>
}

<div class="@_css">@_message</div>

@code{
    [CascadingParameter] private HttpContext? httpContext { get; set; }
    private bool _isInteractive => httpContext is null;
    private bool _isloaded;
    private string _css => _isloaded ? "alert alert-success m-2" : "alert alert-danger m-2";
    private string _message => _isloaded ? "Loaded" : "Loading";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Will only do the data get in interactive mode
        if (_isInteractive)
        {
            // emulate a slow async data load
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            _isloaded = true;
        }
    }
}

